# How to open my cheatsheet programmaticlly in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, rcp

I built my own 'cheat sheet'. How to open it programmatically when I open 'Cheat Sheet  View' as follows?   `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView("org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets.views.CheatSheetView");`

Answer (score 0):

You do not open the CheatSheatView like that. Instead use  `org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets.OpenCheatSheetAction`:

```java
new OpenCheatSheetAction("cheat sheet id").run();
```

This will open the cheat sheet view except if it is called from a `TrayDialog` (or derived class) in which case it will add the sheet to the dialog.

Comment: Wow! I used the code you gave me and my cheat sheet opened directly!

Comment: thank fof your answer. My intention is to show cheat sheet form in my intro screen when I click the 'Tutorails' item on my original intro screen. Is there a way?

Comment: I don't know anything about intro screens as I don't use them.

Comment: Can you tell me how to add a newline in the cheat sheet <description> ? For example aaa<br> bbb<br> cccc<br>

Comment: No, I can't. I don't use them